# How to print entries of AVLTree in Pre-order Traversal

Tags: java, avl-tree

I am trying to print the objects stored in the AVL Tree using preorder Traversal, the program runs fine but it does not print the preorder traversal it just prints the objects in the order they were inserted into the tree. can anyone help me with it?

```
private AVLNode<AnyType> printPreorder(AVLNode<AnyType> t) {
        if (t == null)
            return null;

        /* first print data of node */
        System.out.print(t.element + " ");

        /* then recur on left sutree */
        printPreorder(t.left);

        /* now recur on right subtree */
        printPreorder(t.right);
        return null;

    }


    public AVLNode<AnyType> print() {
        return printPreorder(root);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the last `return`statement, use this code:

```
private Void printPreorder(AVLNode<AnyType> t) 
{   
    if (t != null)
    {
        System.out.print(t.element + " ");
        printPreorder(t.left);
        printPreorder(t.right);
    }
}

public Void print() 
{
        printPreorder(root);
}
```

Do let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: No, it asks me to add a return statement

Comment: See you have no need to “return” anything ... this is a “printing” method the only thing it has to do is to “print” so there is no need to return a “node” !

Comment: @Bapu glad to help :)